# Can logstash output be a directory

Tags: logstash

Does anyone know whether it is possible to ship logs from a directory in a local disk to a directory in NFS through logstash? I know the input can be something like /app/log/*.log, but how can I set up the output?

And another question, if I have multiple applications logging to stdout, how can I create different types for different applications?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect to happen with a directory as output?

Comment: If I set file in input to be INPUT_PATH/ and file in output as OUTPUT_PATH/, I expect all the directories and files in INPUT_PATH/ be copied to OUTPUT_PATH/. Is it possible?

Comment: The [docs](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/file#path) state that `event fields` can be used in the `output path`. So you might me able to parse the `input file` location into a `field` and use it as `output path`. But I'm not sure if that's going to work, hence just a comment, not an answer.